# Postgsql 11 Creating an object using UUID but beforeCreate is not being fired to update the id with UUID before save

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

This seems to occur when using an object as  join table in a M:N association.

The `beforeCreate` hook is not updating the id before DB update.

I have created an instance hook in `postgresql` Version 11 within the instance model.

I have attempted to use both methods 2 and 3 neither of which work. The id column is not updated with `UUID` generated at create time

When I log the value within the hook I have a unique `uuid` but in the creating SQL the default `uuid` is used resulting in unique violation error.

I expected the values in the before hook to be used for the DB create statement

```
Log messages:
UserPersonalRelationship.beforeCreate:  19bbc538-c82e-41f5-9bd3-f0eabf9c0193
UserPersonalRelationship.beforeCreate:  3af7d252-ecfe-49e9-b850-a72a78e9773d
```

In the postgresql error message the field value is shown as:

```
fields: { id: '2cfe1fb0-4b3c-496b-80fe-f9073302afe8' },
```

My instance model is:

```
"use strict";
const { uuid } = require("uuidv4");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const UserPersonalRelationship = sequelize.define(
    "UserPersonalRelationship",
    {
        User_rowID: DataTypes.UUID,
        PersonalRelationship_rowID: DataTypes.UUID,
    },
    {}
);
UserPersonalRelationship.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
};

UserPersonalRelationship.beforeCreate(
    async (userPersonalRelationship, options) => {
        const objUUID = uuid();
        userPersonalRelationship.id = objUUID;
        console.log("UserPersonalRelationship.beforeCreate: ", objUUID);
    }
);
UserPersonalRelationship.addHook(
    "beforeValidate",
    (userPersonalRelationship, options) => {
        userPersonalRelationship.id = uuid();
        console.log("Add hook called");
    }
);

return UserPersonalRelationship;
};
```

Comment: Rather than using a hook, you could instead set `defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4` on the defintiion.

Comment: Given that's a join table, does it make sense to assign them default UUIDs?

Comment: I strongly recommend to use a DB-side generation of PK value by assigning default value in a column in a DB like `uuid_generate_v4()` and define the `id` field in a model explicitly like: `id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    }`. That way you don't need `beforeCreate` hook and moreover if you will insert a record in the table directly it will still have a correct PK value.

Comment: @ Schwern - In Sequelize the default UUID is a  UUID that is generated at when sequelize starts rather than a UUID at the time the record is created

Comment: @Anatoly only works with data types such as integers -  not a UUID that needs to be generated by another npm package. I  get a sequelize error trying to use the autoincrement attribute

Comment: your beforeCreate is using async which is why it is not working. try a sync version and you wont get that error